# Get user input value to use in a variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm pretty new to this and im pretty new to using JS. I'm working through the basics and really getting in to it. However I am having an issue with trying to use a users input to help me in other areas.

I have a little CSS to create an input id="cars" and a button id="submit". I want to use those inputs in a switch statement. This is what I have so far, I will add more to my switch statement once I have managed to get the input value to work.

```
<h1>What is your car?</h1>
<input id="cars" type="text"></input>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clickedCar = document.getElementById("cars").value
    switch(clickedCar){
        case "Honda":
            document.write("Honda are nice cars to drive");
            break;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: What's your question?  What isn't working?

Comment: To elucidate a bit on David's comment, questions asking for help with a specific problem with code need to specify what your problem is. Here you've specified what you want, but now how your code falls short. Without adding that important information, this question risks being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <h1>What is your car?</h1>
 <input id="cars" type="text">
   <button onclick="submitCar()" id="submit">Submit</button>

   <script>
   submitCar = function(){
         var clickedCar = document.getElementById("cars").value
         switch(clickedCar){


     case "Honda":
        document.write("Honda are nice cars to drive");
        break;
}
};
   </script>
```

Here you go, I tried this and it works :)

EDIT:

However I would suggest putting your javascript in a seperate file and don't use 'onclick' in an element but since your new to JS this should work fine for now